# How to use a list passed with {% include with %} in jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, html, django, jinja2

So I am including template with jQuery script and pass there a list of some values.

```
{% block content %}
    {% include 'path/foo.html' with key=val_list %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the foo.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="{% static 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'%}"></script>
<script>

var availableTags = [
    "some",
    "values",
    "here"
];
</script>
```

I want to fill availableTags with list from my key. I can access elements from that list before script using:

```
{% for k in key %}
   {{ k }}
{% endfor %}
```

But can't do that inside script. I think I know why but I don't know how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version 2.1 of Django will make this easier with a new [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter, but if you are limited to version 2.0 or below, you will have to handle it manually. What you need to remember is that the template rendering occurs before the client browser receives the rendered document and executes any JavaScript present. You can use the Django template language in a `script` block, like this:

```
<script>
var availableTags = [
    {% for k in key %}
    "{{ k }}",
    {% endfor %}
];
</script>
```

It will produce this, which will be parsed by the browser:

```
<script>
var availableTags = [
    "some",
    "values",
    "here",
];
</script>
```